# TryCast returns opposite to what I expect

Tags: vb.net

Please take a look at the code below:

```
Imports DataObjects  
Imports BusinessObjects  
Public Class FormMain
Private Sub FormLogin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'InitializeTreeView()
    TreeViewMembers.Nodes.Add("Members")
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeTreeView()
    'Dim objMemberDAO As New MemberDAO
    'Dim theMembers = objMemberDAO.GetMembers
    Dim model As New Model
    Dim theMembers = model.GetMembers()
    For Each member In theMembers
        TreeViewMembers.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(member.name)
        TreeViewMembers.Nodes(0).Tag = member
    Next member
End Sub

Private Sub TreeViewMember_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeViewMembers.AfterSelect
    Try
        InitializeTreeView()
        Dim member = TryCast(TreeViewMembers.SelectedNode.Tag, MemberModel)
        If member Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        'BindLoans(member.Loans)
    Catch EX As Exception
        MsgBox(EX.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

The TryCast returns a MemberModel when the form is loaded for the first time.  When I select a member from the TreeView it returns Nothing.  This is vice versa to what I would expect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, the error seems to be in this block:

```
For Each member In theMembers
    TreeViewMembers.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(member.name)
    TreeViewMembers.Nodes(0).Tag = member
Next member
```

This code sets the tag on the root node, not on the newly created node. So the error is not related to `TryCast`. This works as expected - when the code runs for the first time, you must have selected the root node that the model was set for (in the first version). So `TryCast` returns a Model.

When selecting another member, the tag is not set, so that `TryCast` will return Nothing (input Nothing => output Nothing).

I think changing your code like this should help:

```
For Each member In theMembers
    Dim newNode = TreeViewMembers.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(member.name)
    newNode.Tag = member
Next member
```